# Violation Of Primary Key in ASP.NET and SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I want to add book to my Book_Master table. But I've got an error of Violating Primary Key. I really don't understand of the duplicate value because I am generating bookid (primary key) through code then from where the duplication occur?

[image: Here's the pic]

Comment: Please post your table definition so we can see the constraint. You shouldn't need to insert the identity into a table in SQL Server through your code, it can be set up to automatically increment.

Comment: You're trying to insert data with a value of 9 into that field but you've already got a 9 in there. It's a unique field so you can't have two instances of the same value.

Comment: For emphasis, I'm echoing what Ron is implying and Rich Benner noted below. That code may be vulnerable to a Sql Server Injection attack, something that is commonly exploited. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlphp/2008/09/30/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries/

Comment: Try using auto generated primary keys

Comment: Please paste in your code. We can't copy/paste a screen shot, which makes it hard to offer further corrections.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing:

```
INSERT INTO Book_Master (bookid, booktitle....
```

with:

```
INSERT INTO Book_Master (booktitle....
```

Generally speaking, when inserting into a table with an identity column, you cannot pass your own.

Also please do consider the ramifications of a user entering a book title of:

```
';drop table Book_master
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got the SqlCommand execution in a `for( int i = 0; i < counter ; i++)` loop...but not the generation of the bookid. Google `sql injection` for why that's a really bad way to build a SQL statement.

**Edit:**

So, the basic problem is, you need to add records to the book_detail for as many copies as you have...but just once for book_master.

There are a couple of issues here. First, just do the insert into book_master just once like you have it...by taking the line:

```
for (int i=0; i < counter; i++ ){
```

...and the matching...

```
}
```

...out.

Then, right after `cmdSave.ExecuteNonQuery()`, and using the same open connection, edit the cmd.Command text to insert into the `book_detail`. We don't know what fields go into `book_detail`...but this is the statement that will go inside your loop.

Generally, you want to set up your statements so that you can reuse the statement multiple times...with different parameters. This is how you prevent the sql injection problems people have been trying to warn you about. It looks like this:

```
cmdSave.CommandText = "insert sometable(a,b) values (@a,@b)";
cmdSave.Parameters.Add( "@a", SqlDbType.String, 4 );  // for example
cmdSave.Parameters.Add( "@b", SqlDbType.Int );        // for example

for( int i=0;i<counter;i++){
  cmdSave.Parameters["@a"].Value = GetNextValueA(i);  // for example
  cmdSave.Parameters["@b"].Value = GetNextValueB(i);  // for example
  cmdSave.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I just want to add that many copies of books that are put in run time in quantity text box through loop.... I am not using for-loop for generating bookid

Comment: Right - but you can't put multiple records into book_master if the book_id is the primary key.

Comment: Your insert statement is inside the loop...move it to after the loop

Comment: That's where i am stuck ... I don't have an idea how to save book copies into Book_Detail table in Database ....  I want to save book data in Book_Master table and copies of that book in to Book_Detail... @Clay

Comment: @khaafi, I get it...will edit my answer to outline what to do

Comment: @khaafi, okay, now I'm blushing :-)  Good luck!

Comment: Please give me your email if you want ... it'll be pleasure sir @Clay

Answer (score 0):

Make `bookid` an auto-incrementing number

```
ALTER TABLE book_master ALTER COLUMN bookid INT NOT NULL IDENTITY
```

Comment: I don't want to auto increment bookid .. i want to increment through max query

Comment: Then you are going to need to exclusively lock the table in a serialized transaction. But that opens up it's own set of problems that you aren't ready for, so just use the database in the way it was intended.

Comment: Thanks man ... Actually I am new to programming ... That's why ... Bundle of thanks for your precious answer

Comment: I don't intend to be mean-spirited about this, but I've been doing this for nearly 20 years and even I screw-up half the time when trying to simulate auto-numbering outside of the database.

Comment: @Jonathen Thanks for your time